# NoClassDefFoundError while running app exported as JAR (related to EMC Documentum)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, certificate, classnotfoundexception

I have written an application that uses EMC Documentum Foundation Class library form performing some function on documentum repository. For that I first installed DFC Runtime Environment. It establishes certificates required for communication with Documentum Content server.

When I run project through eclipse it works fine. But when I export it as Runnable JAR, and run it as `java -jar` it shows following exception

[image]

It seems that when exported as JAR, the application is getting into some certificate related issues and trying to throw `CertificateException`, however it is not finding that class.

I tried
 - by putting path to the jar `certjFIPS.jar` (which contains `CertificateException`) that is `c:\Documetum\shared` in `classpath` environment variable.
 - by adding it to project as an external jar

But none worked.
As I examine above stack trace, I realize that the excpetion is thrown by DFC runtime related classes which are running in some certificate related issue. However, it seems that while running through eclipse it is not facing any such issues.

So I will like to know many things here even though the final exception is `NoClassDefFoundError`

- Firstly what should I do just to let JAR find `CertificateException`
- What are possible certificate related changes I have to do when running the same app as a JAR
- What should be different options I should select while exporting project as a JAR in eclipse so that certificate issues will not arise.
- Also as info, I created a link resource in project that points to `c:\Documentum\config`, which contains `dfc.properties` and also `dfc.keystore`. So also is there any way by which I can specify explicitly for JAR to use these two files while running?

Comment: Where is certjFIPS.jar located in your Eclipse project?

Comment: Actually I am not using any class from `certjFIPS.jar` directly in my source. So initially I did not included it in my project and code worked just fine. But when I exported this project as JAR and run, it gave me this error. Seems that DFC runtime environment classes use this class (as can be seen from stack trace). So I just tried by including that JAR in my project and by including its path in classpath and it did not worked. I dont understand why it works when I run it thru eclipse and not when I run JAR.

Comment: You have a problem triggering the need for it.  Export all the jars present in your Java project and the _real_ cause should allow itself to show.

Comment: Yes and that problem is certificate issue caused by DFC runtime, not immediately by my code - check that first 3 `at` lines in stack trace. But this issue is not arising when run through eclipse. And by _export all_ do you mean to select `Package all jars` while exporting? I did it. But since this `certjFIPS.jar` is required by DFC runtime not directly by my code, including it in my project doesn't solve the issue. It is runtime that should find the JAR and it is finding it when run through eclipse but not when run thru JAR. Please correct my understanding if I am wrong.

Comment: As long as  you do not know what the Exception which cannot be thrown would have indicated, you have no idea of what is _really_ wrong.

Comment: Ohkay I know thats pretty weird, but am I thinking it right? Or have any solution / idea for me to try out?